# Get cocos2d-x keyboard info on android

Tags: cocos2d-x

I simply insert following codes in a clean base(at the final of `HelloWorld::init()`) produced by `cocos new`:

```
auto kl = EventListenerKeyboard::create();

kl->onKeyPressed = [](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event) {
    CCLOG("%s> keyCode=%d",__FUNCTION__,keyCode);
};
auto ed = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
ed->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(kl,this);
```

**On windows, it worked well**. But nothing happened on android.
Log with value of `keyCode` should be left in logcat, I think.
Do I miss anything?

Comment: Do you mean you have a hard-keyboard android device ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this issue?  I want to control my game using the keyboard when using the Android Emulator, and the keyboard events simply don't fire.

Comment: @trojanfoe, our solution is here: http://yunpan.cn/ccxjvvtI2Qjqb (extraction code：aa01), it contains some source codes of coco2d-x.

Comment: @naive231 Thanks, but that link doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that. Can I mail attachment to you?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach One:**
If you just need to handle keyboard as `key-event`, It's as easy as these below lines of code:

```cpp
HelloWorld::init()
{ 
    ...
    auto keyboardListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
    keyboardListener->onKeyPressed = [](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:      /*Jump maybe*/  break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_DOWN_ARROW:    /*Crouch maybe*/    break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:   /*Move Right maybe*/    break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_LEFT_ARROW:    /*Move Left maybe*/ break;
        }
    };
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this);
    ...
return true;
}
```

I think it's clear enough not to need any extra description.

**Approach Two:** if you need an `input box` that user/player can enter string with `keyboard` and you get what is entered, I recommend to use `TextField` which is available in cocos2d v3 ( and with some difficulty  in v2) and has a full functionality. You can create and initial one of them as:

```cpp
auto textField = cocos2d::ui::TextField::create("hint: enter here","Arial" , 30);
textField->setTextHorizontalAlignment(cocos2d::TextHAlignment::CENTER);
textField->setTextVerticalAlignment(cocos2d::TextVAlignment::CENTER);
textField->setColor(Color3B(100,100,100));
textField->setMaxLength(10);
textField->setMaxLengthEnabled(true);
textField->setTouchAreaEnabled(true);
textField->setTouchSize(Size(200,400));
textField->setPosition(...);
textField->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::textFieldEvent, this));
this->addChild(textField, 10);
```

You can get entered data any time with `std::string enteredData= textField->getString();`

You can also do something when user entering text with two event as :

```cpp
void HelloWorld::textFieldEvent(Ref *pSender, cocos2d::ui::TextField::EventType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case cocos2d::ui::TextField::EventType::ATTACH_WITH_IME:
    {
        textField->setColor(Color3B::BLACK);
        // or whatever elese
        break;
    }
    case cocos2d::ui::TextField::EventType::DETACH_WITH_IME:
    {
        textField->setColor(Color3B(100,100,100));
        // or whatever elese
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Sorry,buddy. My fault. I didn't mention that I don't use text field.
I just create a new project, and want to get keyboard info from `cocos2d::Layer` object.

Comment: @naive231 I complete my answer with what you need. feedback if you had any probelm.

Comment: I'm using cocos2d-x 3.3, and tried approach 1, on android(4.4.2).
But no key can enter `onKeyPressed` lambda function.
Do you sure it can worked ON ANDROID?

Comment: @naive231 In fact It is a bad idea to use hardware keyboard of phone device if you're going to publish your app/game. there's little device with this capability.

Comment: Thanks your respond. I know your point. So there is truly a wrong assumption. So my test result seems that is correct. No body notices that hardware keyboard **won't** worked well at android platform, right?

We use android system on our embedded platform for game development. For debug purpose, if we can interact with game by keyboard will be very convenient.

Comment: can we restrict other letters like space in our text ?

Comment: can we hide keyboard when we left text filed popup layer ??

Comment: What about EditBox? How to catch "keyboardWillShow" event with it?